# How to generate random numbers with specific probabilities in python?

Tags: python, random

For example,

Try to generate a list of 1000 random numbers with only `0 and 1`.

s.t.

`0 has the prob of 40%`

`1 has the prob of 60%`

thanks!

Comment: `np.asarray(np.random.rand(1000) > 0.4, dtype=int)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

myProb = []

```
for i in range(1000):
#creates one number out of 0 or 1 with prob p 0.4 for 0 and 0.6 for 1
    test = numpy.random.choice(numpy.arange(0, 2), p=[0.4, 0.6])
    myProb.append(test)
```

print(myProb)